# Padding aspect ratio hack, but based on height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Most of you know [a trick](https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video) that makes element scale at a fixed aspect ratio, for example:

```
<div style="width:100%;position:relative">
  <div style="padding-bottom:100%;background:tomato;height:0;">square (1:1)</div>
</div>
```

(jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0dda7939/ )

[image]

I want the same thing, but based on height not based on width.

```
<div style="height:100%;position:relative">
  <div style="??? background:tomato;">square (1:1)</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there any way to do this without JS and without using VW/VH units (since parent container might not always be window)?

Comment: your current fiddle does that, it covers all height and width

Comment: @dippas If you try to reduce width of window - it doesn't, it's aligned to top, not to left. And height is not 100% of window.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0dda7939/1/

Comment: @MarouenMhiri it's not a square, orange rectangle must always be a square, not matter what width or height of window (or parent container) is.

Comment: With JS, it can be easily done. Why you don't want to use JS?

Comment: Finally, finally, there is plain CSS on the way to enable this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Answer (score -1):

With JS it can be done easily. The problem with doing by CSS is applying width equal to the height. If you are comfortable to use SASS, then you can do that. Otherwise, JS (jQuery) solution is given below:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">I am a square (1:1)</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:auto;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative
}

.child {
  background:tomato;
  height:inherit;
}
```

JS:

```
let parentWidth = $('.parent').width();
let parentHeight = $('.parent').height();
let childWidth = $('.child').width();
let childHeight = $('.child').height();
let minSize = 0;
$('.child').width(childHeight);

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  parentWidth = $('.parent').width();
  parentHeight = $('.parent').height();
  childWidth = $('.child').width();
  childHeight = $('.child').height();
  minSize = Math.min(parentWidth, parentHeight);

  if (childWidth >= parentWidth || childHeight >= parentHeight) {
    if (childWidth >= parentWidth && childHeight >= parentHeight) {
      $('.child').height(minSize);
      $('.child').width(minSize);
    } else if (childWidth >= parentWidth) {
      $('.child').width(parentWidth);
      $('.child').height(parentWidth);
    } else {
      $('.child').height(parentHeight);
      $('.child').width(parentHeight);
    }
  } else {
    $('.child').height(minSize);
    $('.child').width(minSize);
  }
});
```

Comment: How can SASS do that?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this code::

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background:tomato;">square (1:1)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to behave as I want -
 https://jsfiddle.net/8mpbygc8/1/

Comment: You have to give a height to the parent div.